# Create a rectangle over canvas to perform click events

Tags: javascript, svg, onclick, raphael

I am trying to setup a rectangle over a canvas to add click event listener to the rectangle.
Basically I need to add click event listener for the canvas but I was not able to achieve that so I took this approach.
Below is the JS & the HTML that is created.

JS

```
var canvasEle = $("#canvas");
var paper = Raphael("the-canvas", canvasEle.width(), canvasEle.height());

var centerX = canvasEle.width()/2;
var centerY = canvasEle.height()/2;
var canvasRect = paper.rect(centerX, centerY, canvasEle.width(), canvasEle.height());
```

SVG that is created.

```
<svg height="150" version="1.1" width="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.4</desc><defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs>
    <rect x="150" y="75" width="300" height="150" rx="0" ry="0" fill="none" stroke="#000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    </rect>
</svg>
```

I am not able to generate the click event for 'canvasRect'.

```
canvasRect.click( function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```

Would appreciate I can know what is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: _Basically I need to add click event listener for the canvas but I was not able to achieve that_ So, if you only want the click on the canvas are you trying to do something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/5daLbLbg/1/

Comment: Yes, I had tried 'paper.click()' but I guess that wasn't correct. I may have overlooked using the code as it is in the fiddle. Thanks @Patchee.

Comment: Note the canvasRect has a fill of 'none' and no stroke, so not sure that the click would work in your example.